# Python code scraping data from kickstarter does not work after some iteration

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape data from kickstarter, the code is working but it gives the following error in page 15 (you might get get error in different page since webpage is dynamic):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\lenovo\kick.py",
> line 30, in 
> csvwriter.writerow(row)   File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
> line 19, in encode
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\uff5c' in
> position 27: character maps to

What might be the issue? Any suggestion?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv
KICKSTARTER_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=16&sort=newest&seed=2502593&page={}"
DATA_FILE = "kickstarter.csv"
csvfile = open(DATA_FILE, 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
page_start = 0
while True:
    url = KICKSTARTER_SEARCH_URL.format(page_start)
    print(url)
    response = urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    project_details_divs = soup.findAll('div', {"class":"js-react-proj-card"})

    if len(project_details_divs) == 0:
        break;

    for div in project_details_divs:
        project = json.loads(div['data-project'])
        row = [project["id"],project["name"],project["goal"],project["pledged"]]
        csvwriter.writerow(row)

    page_start +=1

csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the argument `encoding` to your file-opener. I mean, change

```
csvfile = open(DATA_FILE, 'w')
```

into

```
csvfile = open(DATA_FILE, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

***But*** the practice on that matter is rather to use a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)

```
with open(DATA_FILE, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    # ...
```

Comment: Any question @user229 ?

Comment: It gives the error: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Should I also change file writing? because it again gives error inside for loop, but in the page 1.

Comment: I guess that the answer got downvoted because of the context-manager omission.